# BPMN Intergration?

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 so I just want to make sure I understand it all before I go down the rabbit hole. We currently have a Workflow System that uses very complex data validation input screens. We use the Oracle Workflow engine as the state engine (20 years old version of BPMN). We want to replace it with BPMN. I did read that you are able to interface with the BPMN process via REST. So I just want to make sure that we will be able to still use our complex screens and interface with the BPMN process where we have Human Tasks to do.

So basically I want our external application do all the data validation on user input data, once it is happy with the data it will save it to the database and then start a new instance of the BPMN process. We should set process variables required to do automatic routing by the BPMN process also via the REST interface.

When we have an approval to do the BPMN process will wait at the Human Task in the process until we tell it to follow a certain transition via a REST interface.

Will this be possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is Yes, you can pretty much manage every step of the process through the REST API's that are provided.

For example you can start a process by message, where you send the message required to start a process to the API. So in your example, after validating the user input you can compose the right message and send it to the API to start the process.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Looks like I have a lot of work to do lol